# Inexplicable operator behaviour in Python function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can please someone explain why the the following operations have not equal outcome when passed to a function?

```
lis=lis+[1]
lis+=[1]
```

Shouldn't that be the same?

The problem derives from the following code:

```
def f1(lis):
    lis=lis+[1]
    print(id(lis))

list1=[0]
print("before function", id(list1))
f1(list1)
print("after function", id(list1))
print(list1)
```

> before function 45004000
>   45004160
>   after function 45004000
>   [0]

Why is "1" not added to `list1` like it does below?

```
def f1(lis):
    lis+=[1]
    print(id(lis))

list1=[0]
print("before function", id(list1))
f1(list1)
print("after function", id(list1))
print(list1)
```

> before function 45200888
>   45200888
>   after function 45200888
>   [0, 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you could see from the output for your first snippet, the `id(lis)` changes after you assign `lis + [1]`. What `lis + [1]` does is create a new list, which you then assign back to `lis`. That's why you get different `id`s (45004000 versus 45004160 in your case). This will not persist as a reference to `list1`.

On the other hand, `lis += [1]` **mutates** `lis`, changing it in-place. You can tell it does this in place because of the consistent `id` (45200888 in your output). Being under the same `id` as before, this will persist back to `list1`, mutating it as well.

Comment: thank you very much for this clarification